# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax in while doing migration

Tags: laravel, migration

When I run

`php artisan migrate`

> Following is my schema

```
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('url')->unique()->after('id');
            $table->string('type')->after('meta_data');
            $table->json('meta_data')->change();
            $table->unsignedInteger('status_id')->default(3)->after('type');
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(false)->after('status_id');

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            // Foreign Key
            $table->foreign('status_id')
                ->references('id')->on('statuses')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('is_active');
            $table->dropColumn('status_id');
            $table->dropColumn('type');
            $table->dropColumn('url');
        });
    }
}
```

The following error is showing

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE 
>   pages CHANGE meta_data meta_data JSON CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL)

Comment: `metadata` column is already added in `areas` table?

Comment: No it is not added.

Comment: some `Previous` versions of `mySQL` can not define a field in `JSON`, so you can change it to `LongText`. `$table->longText('metadata')->nullable();`

Comment: I am using `mySQL` version ` 5.7.26` but I want to save data in `json` format

Comment: @AbhishekPakhare if you define field in `longText` also you can store the json values to it, i used this before.

Comment: Sorry, I by mistakenly posted the wrong migration I have updated the code can you please check now.

Answer (score 1):

```
Schema::table('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('url')->unique()->after('id');
            $table->string('type')->after('meta_data');
            $table->longText('meta_data')->change(); //changed to longText
            $table->unsignedInteger('status_id')->default(3)->after('type');
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(false)->after('status_id');

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            // Foreign Key
            $table->foreign('status_id')
                ->references('id')->on('statuses')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

in this case you can store the json values to `metadata` field 
**JUST DO IT IN CONTROLLER**
in your Controller before store ----> `json_encode($metadata_variable);`
and when you want to read or use this ------> `json_decode($metadata);`

i used this and its working fine

Comment: I am working on storing data in the database in `Json` format and want to keep the datatype as `JSON` . Do you know how to store data in that format .

Comment: before store data in your field, convert it to `JSON` by `json_encode` and when you wanted to read it `json_decode` it, it comes back to whatever been before.